# Are there any common benchmarks for multidimentional optimization methods?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am going to implement several swarm-intelligence optimization methods including some of the own ideas and am wondering, are there any universally acknowledged benchmarking functions for these? Since obviously for each of them there is a problem set for which they do their best and accordingly problem set on which they fall behind - so is there any comprehensive one to compare all of them in a more consistent way?